# Bad costmap while using Intel Realsense D435i camera in ROS2 NAV2

Tags: navigation, ros-humble, costmap-2d, realsense-camera

I am using 2 Sicklidars and 1 intel realsense D435i camera for robot navigation.
While using the Lidars for the local costmap and global costmap, everything is good. As soon as I add realsense camera, the costmap is spoiled very badly. I am stuck with this issue since long. Please help.

[image]

Video: https://youtu.be/f_SrVD0Gbvc

ROS2 Parameters:

```
local_costmap:
    local_costmap:
        ros__parameters:
            update_frequency: 5.0
            publish_frequency: 2.0
            global_frame: odom
            robot_base_frame: base_link
            use_sim_time: False
            rolling_window: true
            width: 10
            height: 10
            resolution: 0.05
            # robot_radius: 1.25
            footprint: "[ [0.80, 0.80], [0.80, -0.80], [-0.80, -0.80], [-0.80, 0.80] ]"
            plugins:
                [
                    "voxel_layer_2d",
                    # "voxel_layer_3d",
                    "denoise_layer",
                    "keepout_filter",
                    "inflation_layer",
                ]
            denoise_layer:
                plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::DenoiseLayer"
                enabled: true
                minimal_group_size: 2
                group_connectivity_type: 8
            inflation_layer:
                plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
                cost_scaling_factor: 3.0
                inflation_radius: 1.5
            voxel_layer_2d:
                plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::VoxelLayer"
                enabled: True
                publish_voxel_map: True
                origin_z: 0.0
                z_resolution: 0.05
                z_voxels: 16
                max_obstacle_height: 2.0
                mark_threshold: 0
                observation_sources: scan_1 scan_2 points_2 points_1 
                scan_1:
                    topic: /front_lidar/scan
                    max_obstacle_height: 2.0
                    clearing: True
                    marking: True
                    data_type: "LaserScan"
                    raytrace_max_range: 10.0
                    raytrace_min_range: 0.0
                    obstacle_max_range: 9.5
                    obstacle_min_range: 0.0
                scan_2:
                    topic: /rear_lidar/scan
                    max_obstacle_height: 2.0
                    clearing: True
                    marking: True
                    data_type: "LaserScan"
                    raytrace_max_range: 10.0
                    raytrace_min_range: 0.0
                    obstacle_max_range: 9.5
                    obstacle_min_range: 0.0
                points_1:
                    topic: /camera/depth/color/points
                    max_obstacle_height: 2.0
                    min_obstacle_height: 0.300
                    clearing: False
                    marking: True
                    data_type: "PointCloud2"
                    raytrace_max_range: 4.0
                    raytrace_min_range: 0.40
                    footprint_clearing_enabled: True
                    observation_persistence: 0.0
                    mark_threshold: 10.0
                points_2:
                    topic: /camera/depth/color/points
                    max_obstacle_height: 0.300
                    min_obstacle_height: 0.0
                    clearing: True
                    marking: False
                    data_type: "PointCloud2"
                    raytrace_min_range: 0.40
                    raytrace_max_range: 4.0
                    footprint_clearing_enabled: True
                    observation_persistence: 0.0
                    mark_threshold: 10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either filter your sensor data, calibrate your cameras, or limit the depth in your configuration to the range at which the RGBD cameras are accurate probably a mix of all 4).